# Visual Studio 9.0 Error specifies undefined struct/union

Tags: visual-studio, struct, union, undefined

I'm getting the error in my Visual Studio 9.0 project

```
1>..\..\..\..\..\Work Projects\putty-svn\sshnogss.c(9) : error C2037: left of 'libraries' specifies undefined struct/union 'ssh_gss_liblist'
1>..\..\..\..\..\Work Projects\putty-svn\sshnogss.c(10) : error C2037: left of 'nlibraries' specifies undefined struct/union 'ssh_gss_liblist'
```

and I'm not sure why for either. The code is:

```
struct ssh_gss_liblist *ssh_gss_setup(Conf *conf)
{
    struct ssh_gss_liblist *list = snew(struct ssh_gss_liblist *);
    list->libraries = NULL;
    list->nlibraries = 0;
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Well... are you _sure_ the file that defines that struct is being `#include`d correctly?

Comment: The problem was that the project didn't include sshgss.h for some reason. It was resolved after I added the #include

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include `sshgss.h`. Have you checked that that file's path  is in the list of paths in INCLUDE list?

Comment: When I do that I get 289 errors about unresolved external errors. How do I go about fixing that?

Comment: Read each error. Investigate. You need to understand the code you're building in more detail. There are lots of conditionals you need to be certain of to ensure you build what you need.

Comment: Alright, thanks. The .obj files are generating, but I'm still getting errors about the unresolved external errors and functions already defined. I'm thinking that it has to do with recursively included header files. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: In that case you now have linkage errors. Ensure that all the dependant libraries are in the LIB path.

Answer (score 0):

[Compiler Error C2037](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa229188%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

> The expression before the member-selection operator ( -> or .) identified a structure or union type that was not defined.